# If the property of the parent DIV is" Position:Fixed", then the Scroll of the Iframe is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scrollmagic

**I am not good at English, so I ask questions using a translator.**

**I'm sorry.**

I use the ScrollMagic library

Created a Mobile Page.

**For ScrollMagic to work**

**html, body's height should be 100%.**

Content Inside has an Iframe.

The Position property of the parent DIV of the Iframe is Fixed.

*PC: Put your cursor over the iframe, scroll, scroll, and you won't scroll.*

*Mobile: Put your cursor on the Iframe and touchMove, you can't scroll.*

**If I scroll "iFrame,"**

 **I want to scroll ".a, .b" instead.**

**Below is an example source**

> HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="content">

  <div class="a">
    TOP
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    BOTTOM
  </div>


  <div class="item">
      <iframe src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" scrolling="no"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

> CSS

```
html, body, .wrap {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:white;
}

.a, .b {
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;

  z-index:2;
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
  height:120%;
}

.b {
  background-color: blue;
  height:50%;
  bottom:0px;
}

.item {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  top:20%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:3;
}

.item iframe {
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  }
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/kasthe/L63krjdc/10/)

**Setting the IFRAM's property to "pointer-events: none" will work.**

**But click should be possible in the IFRAM,**

So I'm looking for another way.

If you have any good information, please let me know.

Comment: I find it a bit hard to unstand what you want and what the problem but is this what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/02cphzyx/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen It's hard to understand what I'm saying, right? I'm sorry

Comment: Summary = 1. IFrame should scroll .a, .b instead of scrolling.

Comment: 2. IFRAME scrolling attribute is no

Comment: 3. IFRAM MUST BE CLEARable